# How does the galois group behaves with polynomial w/ an example??

Tags: group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, automorphism-group, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group modulo 16, i.e, $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

So we know
$$
G = \{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}.
$$
Now, we have a cyclic group $\langle 3 \rangle = \{1, 3, 9, 11\}$ as a subgroup.

So we can have the quotient group that consists of 2 cosets:
$$
Z = G/\langle 3 \rangle = \{\{1, 3, 9, 11\}, \{5, 7, 13 ,15\}\}.
$$
Let denote $H_1 = \{1, 3, 9, 11\}$ and $H_2 = \{5, 7, 13, 15\}$.

On the other hand, we have $(X^8 + 1) \equiv f_1(X)f_2(X) \mod 3 $.

And the following holds $\mathcal{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}[\zeta]/\mathbb{Q}) \cong G$.

Question 1: Is it possible to determine $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(X)$ with $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively??
Let $f_1(X) = a_4 X^4 + a_3 X^3 + a_2 X^2 + a_1 X + a_0$ and $f_2(X) = b_4 X^4 + b_3 X^3 + b_2 X^2 + b_1 X + b_0$.
Is there any relationship between coefficients of $f_1(X)$, $f_2(X)$ and  $H_1, H_2$?

Question 2: If some permutation $\sigma_i$ for $i \in G$  in the Galois group is applied, is there any $i$ that swaps $f_1(X)$ and $f_2(X)$??

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by saying that two cosets are not isomorphic.

Comment: Sorry, that wrong thing is included in an unknown way (even unknown for me..). So Ive just deleted it

Comment: You have used the symbol $\zeta$ without defining it.

Comment: I am assuming they mean $\zeta_{16}$, a primitive root of $X^{16} - 1$, because it would make sense based on context. But I am still not sure what the question 1 is asking.

Comment: Yes, $\zeta$ is a primitive root of $X^{16}-1$.

Comment: I added more explanation for question 1:)

Comment: I believe the relationship is that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $\prod_{j\in H_1}(x-\zeta^j)$ and $\prod_{j\in H_2}(x-\zeta^j)$.

Comment: Does that seem right, mallea?

Comment: Earth to mallea; come in, please.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I think so too!!